# Problem 5-12 John Lee's Smooth Manifolds. A smooth covering map restricted to a component of the boundary is a smooth covering map onto a component

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

This is a problem I got stuck on while studying John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Problem 5-12. Suppose $E$ and $M$ are connected smooth manifolds with boundary, and $\pi : E \to M$ is a smooth covering map, i.e. $\pi$ is smooth surjective and each point in $M$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that each component of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is mapped diffeomorphically onto $U$ by $\pi$. Show that the restriction of $\pi $ to each connected component of $\partial E$ is a smooth covering map onto a component of $\partial M$.

**My attempt so far:**
Let $F$ be a connected component of $\partial E$. Let $x \in \pi(F)$, and let $U$ be an evenly covered neighborhood of $x$. Take $e \in F$ such that $\pi(e)=x$. Let $\tilde U$ be the component of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ containing $e$. Then $\pi|_{\tilde U} : \tilde{U} \to U$ is a diffeomorphism by assumption. Since $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism, $\pi$ maps boundary points to boundary points, so we have $\pi(\tilde{U} \cap F) = U \cap \partial M$.

But this is not really getting me further. I need to show that first, the image $\pi(F)$ is a connected component of $\partial M$. And then for each $x \in \pi(F)$, there is an evenly covered neighborhood $U$ such that each component of $\pi^{-1}(U) \cap F$ is mapped diffeomorphically onto $U \cap \pi(F)$ by $\pi$.

How could I prove this? This problem is in a chapter on submanifolds, but I cannot see how I could use theorems on embedded submanifolds  here.

Comment: Well, you first show that $\pi(F)$ is connected, hence, is contained in a component $G$ of $\partial M$. Then show that $\pi(F)$ is open in $G$; then verify that it is closed in $G$. For the latter, use the definition of a closed subset as the complement to an open subset.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So by connected you mean we need to show that $\pi(F)$ is connected in the topology of $\partial(M)$ right? Since $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism, would we get $\pi(\partial(E)) = \partial(M)$? I know this is the case if $\pi$ is a homeo/diffeomorphism, but I'm nost sure this holds for local diffeomorphisms as well. In that case, we would easily get the first result from continuity. I don't have much clue how to show that $\pi(F)$ is clopen in $G$ though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly argue that $\pi$ maps boundary points to boundary points. Similarly $\pi$ maps interior points to interior points and we conclude that $\pi^{-1}(\partial M) = \partial E$. Hence the restriction  $\pi' : \partial E  \to \partial M$ of $\pi$ is a smooth covering map. Note that for any topological covering map $p : X \to Y$ and for any $A \subset Y$ the restriction $p' : p^{-1}(A)  \to A$ of $p$ is a covering map.

Now let $\{F_\iota\}_{\iota \in I}$ be the components of $\partial E$. Since $\partial E$ is a manifold, it is locally connected and hence the $F_\iota$ are open in $\partial E$. We conclude that the $G_\iota = \pi'(F_\iota)$ are connected open subsets of $\partial M$.

We claim that each $G_\iota$ is closed in $\partial M$, i.e. a *clopen connected subset* of $\partial M$. Such a set is obviously a *component*.

So let us assume that $G_\iota$ is not closed, i.e. there exists a point $x \in \overline G_\iota \setminus G_\iota$. Since $\partial M$ is locally connected, we find an open connected neigborhood $U$ of $x$ in $\partial M$ which is evenly covered by $\pi'$. Then $(\pi')^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of open $V_\alpha \subset \partial E$ which are mapped by $\pi'$ homeomorphically onto $U$. We have $U \cap G_\iota \ne \emptyset$. Choose $y \in F_\iota$ such that $\pi'(y) \in U \cap G_\iota$. Then $y \in (\pi')^{-1}(U)$ so that $y \in V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. But $V_\alpha \approx U$ is connected, thus $F'_\iota = F_\iota \cup V_\alpha$ is connected. Since $F_\iota$ is a component, we infer that $F'_\iota = F_\iota$, i.e. $V_\alpha \subset F_\iota$. This shows $x \in U = \pi'(V_\alpha) \subset \pi'(F_\iota) = G_\iota$ which contradicts the choice of $x$.

**Edited:**

The proof that $\pi' : \partial E  \to \partial M$ maps components onto components works for any covering map $p : X \to Y$ with a *locally connected* $X$. Note that in that case also $Y$ must be locally connected since $p$ is a local homeomorphism.

Now let $F$ be a component of $X$ and $G = p(F)$ be the corresponding component of $Y$. Obviously $p_F : F \to G$ is a continuous surjection. To see that it is a covering map, consider $x \in G$. Since $Y$ is locally connected, $G$ is open and we can find a connected open neigborhood $U$ of $x$, $U \subset G$, which is evenly covered by $p$. Then $p^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of open $V_\alpha \subset X$, $\alpha \in J$, which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$. The $V_\alpha$ are connected, thus we have either $V_\alpha \subset F$ or $V_\alpha \cap F = \emptyset$ since $F$ is a component of $X$. We see that
$$p_F^{-1}(U) = p^{-1}(U) \cap F$$
is the disjoint union of sets $V_\alpha$ with $\alpha  \in J'$ for a suitable $J' \subset J$. This shows that $p_F$ is a covering map.

Comment: So we have $\pi': \partial E \to \partial M$ is a smooth covering map and each component $F_i$ of $\partial E$ is mapped onto a component $G_i$ of $\partial M$ by $\pi'$. From this we conclude that $\pi'$ restricted to $F_i$ is a smooth covering map, since $\pi'|_{F_i}$ smooth (since both $F_i$ and $G_i$ are open subsets there are no issues of smoothness when domain and codomain are restricted) and for each point $x \in G_i$, since $G_i$ is a connected open set in $\partial M$, and $\pi'$ is a smooth covering map, we have an evenly covered neighborhood $U$ in $\partial M$,

Comment: which can be further restricted to a connected neighborhood inside $G_i$ (e.g. take the intersection of $G_i \cap U$ and find a connected base inside by local connectedness of $G_i$), so we have an evenly covered neighborhood for $x$ in $G_i$. Is this the correct argument for completing the smooth covering map argument?

Comment: Yes. You only need to know that (1) $\pi' : \partial E \to \partial M$ is smooth (2)  $\pi'$ is a covering map. The latter is a purely topological argument.

Comment: Why are the components of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ contained in $\delta E$?? Did you mean $\pi'^{-1}(U)$? I mean $U$ is not contained in $\delta E$, right?

Comment: @MSV We consider the covering map $\pi' : \partial E \to \partial M$ and $U \subset \partial M$ which is open in the subspace topology. It would in fact be better to write $(\pi')^{-1}(U)$. However, we have $(\pi')^{-1}(U) =  \pi^{-1}(U)$ since $\pi^{-1}(\partial M) = \partial E$.

Comment: Ah right. I was thinking since you picked an $x$ in the closure but not the set, that the neighborhood would not be contained in $\delta M$, but this is not true.